# How to control which client mist is using as blockchain backend?

Tags: go-ethereum, clients, mist, json-rpc, cpp-ethereum

Whenever I run mist without any client, it launches a `geth` node in the background, connects to the network and syncs the blockchain.

If I have a `geth` node running and start mist, it detects the running node and directly connects to it.

But if I have both `geth` and `eth --listen 30304` running at the same time, mist always tends to connect to the `eth` node. Why is it preferring `eth`?

How to tell mist to use `geth` rather than `eth`? Is it possible to control that behaviour?

Comment: The next release of Mist will have an option build in where you can select which client it should use, I'm not 100% sure this applies to both the build-in client and a self-started one however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabian the Mist developer here.

I never tried your use case actually. But I assume eth is overwriting geth UNIX socket, as they both use the same socket path.

I can't control that behavior if am already running node and would consider this a very unusual edge case, running two nodes :)

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Which unix socket path is used?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/master/modules/ipc/getIpcPath.js